# Squeaking sneakers

Tags: shoes

I have been wearing my new sneakers for a few weeks now and they keep squeaking. I tried the powder trick, and it worked for only one shoe. I then tried walking in the other one without the insole, and it still squeaks.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and foremost thing: identify the part where sound comes.

Once you identified the part, try sprinkling some water absorbing powder.

If there powder technique does not solve, try leather conditioners. Rub some leather onto the shoe, then run with dry clothes. Also, take care when using leather conditioners as some would not be marching your shoes material.

If the shoe is new, then the sound must be a manufacturing defect. Try reaching out to the shop or as the time passes by, the sound might fade away.

Other solutions are as follows:

- Find it there are any defects for the shoe. In this case a cobbler can only help you back.
- If you find the cause of sound is insole, then try planning paper towels between your for pass and insole
- The sound can also be because of left over water droplets at any party of the shoe. Try to wipe it out using a piece of cotton.
- If you stop find squeaking, try applying some coconut oil (in very less quantity as ants would annoy you later because of this) at the affected part.

Answer (score -1):

Rub the bottom of the shoe with a bar of soap. My shoes squeak on the tile floor at work, and the soap actually worked. It does wear off throughout the day, though so you might want to keep a bar stashed somewhere.

Comment: Note this can make surfaces very slippery for you ***and others***.  The risk of you or someone else sliding and falling is not worth it, IMO.  A broken hip for an elderly person often leads to the end of their life.